# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 90221 > 65536)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

Each time I compile my **android studio** app to an **APK** I get this error message.
My android studio version:

[image]

Error Messages:

[image]

[image]

How do you fix this error? It would be greatly appreciated if someone told me how to fix it.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47572185/6551624) answer

Comment: Thank you. I would never have found that, without you linking it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you must enable **multiDexEnabled** just beneath your minSdkVersion in the **build.gradle(:app)**.

```
multiDexEnabled = true;
```

The background reason for this I have not yet fully investigated since in some instances, it will only fail during the **building of the app-bundle** and not on **emulator**.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this fix: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHFBRT9pzaQ&ab_channel=WEBKIH
In build.gradle file, add in default config: multiDexEnabled true

For me it worked.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31259158)